# What is the XML spec for importing into Microsoft Project?

Tags: xml, ms-project

From our existing, internal tracking system I would like to create an XML export that I can then bring into Microsoft Project 2007 to further display and manipulation.  I've been unable to find a straightforward explanation of how the XML should look for this kind of import.  I want to be able to create dependencies, assign resources, etc.  The Excel/CSV imports don't appear to offer all these capabilities so I think XML is the better way...if I could just get a spec for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.project.developer/browse_thread/thread/8fa692c4b60d015a) answered my question.  The spec is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428843.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in Java or a .Net language, you may find it convenient to use [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) to achieve this, rather than writing the XML directly as it provides a more "user friendly" API, insulating you from the detail of the XML schema. It will also allow you to read/write other project data formats if required.

Jon

p.s. Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ, hence my interest!